# Is there a way to allow speech recognition to continually transcript? (python)

Tags: python, speech-recognition, google-text-to-speech

I'm new to coding and Python and at a little bit of a crossroads with this project I'm tackling.
I'm wanting the try a version that continually transcripts (and translates) *as* words are being spoken. Currently it waits for a period of silence before transcripting what was spoken. Do you know of any method do accomplish this? Is it more a matter of using alternative speech recognition/translating modules?

Here is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()
with mic as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.3)
    audio = r.listen(source)
    transcript = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print(transcript)


from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
result = translator.translate(transcript, dest='de')
print(result.dest)
print(result.text)
print(result.pronunciation)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you for this. It's a place to start.